# MySql not saving correct float value

Tags: mysql

I have tickets table with nat_curr_amount of type float. Why is it not saving correct value for higher values?

```
mysql> update tickets set nat_curr_amount = 60.5 where id = 19;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1 Changed: 1 Warnings: 0

mysql> select nat_curr_amount from tickets where id = 19;
+-----------------+
| nat_curr_amount |
+-----------------+
| 60.5            |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update tickets set nat_curr_amount = 600004.5 where id = 19;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)
Rows matched: 1 Changed: 1 Warnings: 0

mysql> select nat_curr_amount from tickets where id = 19;
+-----------------+
| nat_curr_amount |
+-----------------+
| 600004          |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update tickets set nat_curr_amount = 6000004.5 where id = 19;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1 Changed: 1 Warnings: 0

mysql> select nat_curr_amount from tickets where id = 19;
+-----------------+
| nat_curr_amount |
+-----------------+
| 6000000         |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: what is the datatype of nat_curr_amount in your table?

Comment: normally it should be decimal(15,x) and put in x the number of decimals you accept for your values. like decimal(15,6) as 12344.444354

Comment: @Nbenz datatype is float, it's a Rails application

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse the output with the actual value that is stored.

> From
> [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html)
> manual:
>
> The FLOAT and DOUBLE types represent approximate numeric data values.
> MySQL uses four bytes for single-precision values

You can use format() or cast() to decimal to verify the correct values stored.

```
create table tickets (
id int, 
nat_curr_amount  float );
Insert into tickets  values
(19, 20);


update tickets set nat_curr_amount = 600004.5 where id = 19;


select nat_curr_amount from tickets where id = 19;
```

> ```
> Result:
>
>     nat_curr_amount
>     600004
> ```

```
select format(nat_curr_amount, 3) from tickets where id = 19;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> format(nat_curr_amount, 3)
>  600,004.500
> ```

For precise calculation I suggest using decimal rather than float.

Check [Problems with Floating-Point Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-float.html)